# One bluetooth device with multiple apps

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am writing an android app to connect with BLE heart rate monitor devices.
All works well until another application tries to connect to the same service on the BLE device.

Only one application seems to be able to connect at a time.

Is it possible to connect the same BLE service to multple apps at once?

I set up my Bluetooth service in accordance with [Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html) :

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `BluetoothManager.getConnectedDevices()` to get a list of Bluetooth devices, even ones not connected by your app.  Unfortunately, you don't also get the service information for those devices.

What you can do then, is connect to the ones not already connected by your app and perform service discovery on them (`BluetoothDevice.connectGatt()` / `BluetoothGatt.discoverServices()`), then disconnect those that you aren't interested in.  It's a bit cumbersome, but it seems to work for us.

Comment: Thanks, got it working! I'm just using this as a fallback if there is no device found using alternative means.

Comment: Make sure, you do discoverServices once the device is connected(onConnectStateChange), or it will cause errors.

Answer (score 0):

**No** you can not do that, this is something is not supported in BLE.

Comment: Ah, that's unfortunate. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @AAnkit is this supported in classic bluetooth?